# How to reverse the screen like in a mirror, while keeping the mouse movement with Wayland?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, graphics, mirror

I asked [similar questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742592/is-it-possible-to-reverse-the-screen-like-in-a-mirror-with-only-1-monitor) and successfully mirrored (switch right to left and vice versa) my device's only screen on X, while [retaining the mouse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742864/how-would-the-mouse-behave-in-a-mirrored-environment)'s movement like normal. However, such command processes in those answers don't apply to Fedora 38 Gnome, which runs on Wayland, so I'm stuck for now. Could you help? Thanks!